# How to transfer data among APIs

Tags: jmeter

We have tried everything could someone please help us for the solution

I am sending a Get Request and getting this response {"UserID":"123456","SecurityApp":"123456"}

I want to save "UserID" content to a variable and also "SecurityApp" content to a variable and then use it in multiple POST request content

Comment: can you share what is everything that you have tried?

Comment: It could be whatever we tried is incorrect could you please give us some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Regular Expression Extractor component of  JMETER...

You will get both the UserID and SecurityApp using Regx Extractor.

and you can use those variables in subsequent requests...

Answer (score 0):

There is a test element designed for extraction of data from [JSON](http://www.json.org/) structures - [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/). It's available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) - a set of custom extensions which make working with JMeter (and especially reporting) much more easier.

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for installation and usage instructions.

For particular your case detailed steps will be:

1. Download [Extras with Libs Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasWithLibsSet/) bundle to your JMeter installation root and unpack it.
2. Restart JMeter if it is running - plugins are not being picked up dynamically
3. Add a JSON Path Extractor as a child of the request which produces that *UserID/SecurityApp* response
4. Configure it as follows:

   - Variable Name: anything meaningful (i.e. `UserID`)
   - JSON Path: `$.UserID`
5. Repeat step 4 but this time provide `$.SecurityApp` as JSONPath and `SecurityApp` as a Variable Name.
6. After Post Processor's execution you will be able to refer extracted values as `${UserID}` and `${SecurityApp}` wherever required in current Thread Group.